# Apache restarts while trying to create the table in oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

While I am trying to install **phpbb3.1.4** with Oracle11g I am getting the following error exactly when it tries to creates the table.

> Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.9.0, time stamp:
>   0x53258cd5 Faulting module name: OraOCIEI11.dll, version: 11.2.0.1,
>   time stamp: 0x4bb1daeb Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x00000000020c8d57 Faulting process id: 0x1a08 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d0c91f887bd678 Faulting application path:
>   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe Faulting module path:
>   D:\app\username\product\11.2.0\client_1\OraOCIEI11.dll Report Id:
>   e1ecbaaa-3513-11e5-ac90-0021ccd1fa49

there is no error in apache/php logs because I think server restarts automatically !!
Any help ?

Comment: did you tried connecting database directly through sqlplus, where the apache resides?

Comment: Yes! Its working :( actually I figured it something, I checked on my colleague system its working, but not on my system. Probably some miss configuration is there. I checked it even to uninstall the wamp and oracle client on my machine but no luck :(